# Update minify.css file in Wordpress with master CSS file

Tags: css, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

Is there any way to update the minify CSS file based on the changes made in the master CSS file. Tried out with different plugins(WP Super minify). Any help would be much appreciable.

Comment: can you give some more details as to the WP environment - for example what template are you using if any?

Comment: I'm using the Bhoga theme. I'm trying to reduce the font-size by adding some CSS in the master file but aren't reflected. Once I make the changes in min.css, the changes are impacted. Does it depend on themes? Thanks.